# Choosing file enconding in R

Tags: r, encoding

In `R`, I am doing

```
cat("a string", file="myFile.txt")
```

How can I choose the enconding of "myFile.txt"? I want it to be UTF8 without BOM.

Comment: From `?cat`:  "Character strings are output ‘as is’ (unlike print.default which escapes non-printable characters and backslash — use `encodeString` if you want to output encoded strings using cat)."

Answer (score 0):

You could always add or don't add the BOM manually.

```
write_utf8 <- function(x, file, use.bom = FALSE) {
  handle <- file(file, "wb")
  if (use.bom) writeBin(charToRaw('\xEF\xBB\xBF'), con, endian = "little")
  writeBin(charToRaw(x), con, endian = "little")
  close(handle)
  TRUE
}
```

(note that UTF-8 is used by default)